# Unable to run .rb files on mac - getting /.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'

Tags: ruby, macos, selenium

I copied a testscripts folder on my mac, installed ruby step by step from this site:  https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite

When I'm trying to run any .rb file its throwing error:
/Users/**/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver (LoadError)
    from /Users/**/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
    from create_new_course.rb:2:in `'

I searched for such errors all over and none of the posted on solution helped me. Any Suggestion? Is this becuase I have to copy the scriptf folder in specific location only.

Also when I am running Rake command its throwing below error:

rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver
/Users/**/Documents/**/**/tests/**/Rakefile:4:in `'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Has anyone came across this error? Any suggestions on this would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You likely don't have the selenium-webdriver gem installed. In your terminal execute:

`gem install selenium-webdriver`

This is assuming you have ruby gems installed, if that command doesn't work, download ruby gems from https://rubygems.org/pages/download.